# Is it possible to convert PDF to TXT file using GhostScript?

Tags: pdf, conversion, ghostscript

Someone wants to convert PDF to TXT as explained in [C# GhostScript - Not able to successfully convert from PDF to TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710046/c-ghostscript-not-able-to-successfully-convert-from-pdf-to-txt-file).

I am not sure whether GhostScript can do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is absolutely possible. Using the following batch file.

```
rem batch.bat
rem %1 represents input file name without extension.
echo off
gswin32c -q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dSIMPLE -c save -f ps2ascii.ps %1.pdf -c quit >%1.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

command line tool [**pdftotext**, part of the Xpdf open source project](http://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html)

```
NAME
       pdftotext - Portable Document Format (PDF) to text converter (version 3.00)

SYNOPSIS
       pdftotext [options] [PDF-file [text-file]]

DESCRIPTION
       Pdftotext converts Portable Document Format (PDF) files to plain text.

       Pdftotext  reads  the  PDF file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, text-file.  If text-file is not specified, pdftotext con-
       verts file.pdf to file.txt.  If text-file is ´-', the text is sent to stdout.
```

*further details in the [pdftotext man page](http://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html)*

Comment: Check out the `-layout` option. You might want to disable page numbers etc. (i.e. `\pagestyle{empty}`).